# Pass environment variable through Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-explorer

I want to set an environment variable, and then spawn a Windows Explorer window in such a way that processes launched from this new Explorer window inherit that environment variable. I want to do this, so that a diff tool I am integrating with the TortoiseSVN shell extension has access to project-specific environment variables set in a project startup script. But the obvious ways of doing this seem to lose the environment variable somewhere:

1. launch cmd.exe
2. `set MYVAR="foo"`
3. `set | findstr MYVAR`
4. Result contains MYVAR="foo"
5. `explorer .`
6. From the resulting Explorer window, Shift+Right-click a folder and choose "Open Command Window Here"
7. `set | findstr MYVAR`
8. Result does not contain MYVAR

I have set my Windows Explorer settings to [spawn a new process for each Explorer window](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-start-explorer-in-a-separate-process-in-windows-8-1-windows-8-and-windows-7/), hoping that would help, but it seems to have no effect.

I can use `setx` instead of `set` to store the variable globally, however if I want multiple windows to have different versions of MYVAR (e.g. if I'm working on multiple projects at once), this will not work.

Is there a way to set an environment variable specific to a Windows Explorer window, which will be inherited by all its child processes?

Comment: Explorer processes inherit their environment from the process that's running the start menu, to my knowledge. You can reset that environment by logging off and back on, or by closing the process and restarting it with Task Manager, but I don't know of any way to instance a new `explorer.exe` process with a different environment while maintaining a different environment variable set (other than using a different user). I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft specifically checks to make sure this *doesn't* happen.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like an XY problem. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?  Why not use batch scripting or the command line with a command line svn client, which usually installs with TortoiseSVN to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is configured to launch a special diff tool for certain binary files, and this diff tool needs to know where to find a project-specific directory for some additional configuration before processing the diff. Other tools in my environment already use an environment variable set by a project startup script to find this directory. So my goal is to use that environment variable (which changes per-project) in the diff tool. Since TortoiseSVN launches through Windows Explorer, I want to get Windows Explorer to pass that environment variable to TortoiseSVN (and onward to the diff tool).

Comment: You may be right, in that if the solution involves a lot of scripting and invoking special commands to launch an explorer window...it may be easier just to code up tools to invoke the TortoiseSVN dialogs directly, with proper environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open CMD

   setx foo bar
2. Start explorer

   start .
3. Open a new command window (Shift+Right-click a folder)
4. type

   set foo
5. Output

   foo=bar
6. Now if you go back to the cmd opened in 2 and type

   setx foo bar2

the CMD opened in 3 will still show

```
>set foo
foo=bar
```

But if you open a new CMD.EXE from an explorer from the CMD opened in 6 you will get

```
>set foo
foo=bar2
```

This works because SETX passes variables created or modified to *future* command windows but not in the current or already created CMD.exe.

Comment: This works because setx.exe updates the environment variable values in the registry and then broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497) message to top-level windows. Explorer receives the message that the environment settings were modified, so it reloads its own environment from the registry. Subsequently a new instance of cmd.exe started from Explorer gets a copy of the updated environment.

Comment: The problem is that it persistently modifies the environment. The last value will be remembered across sessions. If that's a problem, setx iwill have to be called a final time to delete the variable.

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround, as long as I'm only working on one project at a time. But since *all* new processes created from explorer will inherit the last variable from `setx`, the options for working multiple projects at once are limited.

Answer (score 0):

A program gets a copy of it's starting process environment variables. So this works if you a spawning a new process (a setting in Folder Options - View).

```
Set a=fred
explorer.exe

set a=cat
explorer.exe
```

and remember you have to specify the `/n` command line parameters to force two windows at one folder.

Comment: That's exactly how I thought it worked, but see my example. cmd.exe launched from the explorer window for some reason does NOT get a copy of the variable I set prior to launching explorer.exe.

Comment: Remember it's a new process not a new window. I'm watching task manager and everytime I create a new process it switches to an existing one. Why do you need explorer anyway. this code gives you a explorer type thing `(<html> <body> <iframe src="file:///c:/" width="100%" height="99%"> </body> </html>` (name it something.hta)

Comment: Yes, I have the option set to create a new process for each window, and I also tried using the explicit `explorer /separate` method of starting a new explorer process. Both have the same result, that neither explorer window in your example can start a new process with *any* value for the `a` variable you are setting. I need the Explorer window to launch shell extension tools, such as TortoiseSVN, and I need those tools to have an environment variable set.

Comment: Try the hta. It's the same object that shows files in explorer, just in a different host.

Comment: Hmm, the .hta works but is really limited. For example, if I browse to a subdirectory, I can't go "back" or "up a level", at least not in any way I can see. So it looks like this solution will take a bunch of coding to create a replacement for a real explorer window.

Comment: How does explorer actually start it. If via file associations then put a batch there and use set and then issue the explorer command in batch.